# Reset Redux-Form after server response

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to work out how to reset my form fields when the server responds with a 200 success message. All the examples seem to be focused on clearing the fields when the submission succeeds (regardless of the server response) but I don't want to clear the fields if there was a 400 response from the server.

In my container component I have:

```
submit = (data) => {
  axios.post("/path/to/server", data)
    .then((response) => {
      //reset form somehow
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //keep values in form and show error message
    })
}
```

and I render the form using:

```
<SubscribeForm onSubmit={this.submit} />
```

In my presentational component I have:

```
let MyForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email">Email Address:</label>
      <Field name="email" component="input" type="text"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
  );
}

// Decorate the form component
MyForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
})(MyForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `redux-form` the form state is stored within your `redux` store. So, resetting your form is essentially an action that mutates that state.

Based on this, I would try to find a way to reset form state from [the action creators that `redux-form` passes as props](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/Props.md/) to the decorated form component. Conveniently you will find one named `reset`.

The next challenge is how to dispatch a `reset` action from within your `onSubmit` callback. From [the docs](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/), you can see that `onSubmit` is passed three arguments: `values`, `dispatch` and `props`. These nicely give us the tools to dispatch the `reset` action. Additionally you can resolve your fail case with a [SubmissionError](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/SubmissionError.md/), which will make sure the error-related props are set properly in the decorated form component. For example like this:

```
submit = (values, dispatch, props) => {
  axios.post("/path/to/server", values)
    .then((response) => {
      //reset form somehow
      dispatch(props.reset())
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      //keep values in form and show error message
      return new SubmissionError({
        _error: 'Generic submission failed message here!'
      })
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I didn't see from the docs that dispatch was provided to the onSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with "react refs" https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

If you put a ref to your form component, then you can call:

```
<form ref="formRef" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
...

this.refs.formRef.reset();
```

You just have to make sure, to have access to "this.refs" or pass it further.